# Calculating exact trig value with double angle formula leads me to find two values for cot(pi/12) when there is only one.

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials

Using the double angle formula of $\tan(x)$ and knowing that $\cot(\dfrac{\pi}{6} ) = \sqrt3$ we can make progress towards finding the value of $\cot(\dfrac{\pi}{12})$.

$\cot(2x) = \dfrac{1-\tan^2(x)}{2\tan(x)}$

$\cot(\dfrac{\pi}{6}) = \dfrac{1-\dfrac{1}{\cot^2(\pi/12)}}{2(\dfrac{1}{\cot(\pi/12)})}$

$2\sqrt3=\cot(\dfrac{\pi}{12})-\dfrac{1}{\cot(\pi/12)}$

$\cot^2(\dfrac{\pi}{12})-2\sqrt3 \cot(\dfrac{\pi}{12})-1=0$

We can solve the last line with the quadratic formula and it tells us that:

$\cot(\dfrac{\pi}{12})=2+\sqrt3$ or $-2+\sqrt3$

But this second solution is wrong? Of course $\cot$ can't have two values for one input, but where does this second solution come from?

Comment: $\cot\frac \pi{12}$ is positive , so the first solution is correct, not the second.

Comment: @bernard Thank-you for informing me on how to quickly figure out which one is correct, do you know why there even is an incorrect answer in the first place? Where does it come from?

Comment: Simply when you use the quadatic equation, it does not result from a logical equivalence, only an implication, so you may obtain spurious solutions –¥ exactly in the same way as when to solve $\sqrt A=B$, you convert it to $A=B^2$. If you don't want to have to check, here you can write $\frac\pi{12}=\frac\pi 3-\frac\pi 4$.

Answer (score 4):

There are two angles $\theta$ in $[0,2\pi)$ with a cotangent of $\sqrt 3$.  One is $\frac \pi 6$ and one is $\frac {7 \pi}6$.  This is because adding $\pi$ to the angle changes both the cosine and sine to their negatives, so the signs divide out.  Half of the first is $\frac \pi{12}$ and half of the second is $\frac {7 \pi}{12}$.  They are both solutions to an angle that is half an angle with cotangent of $\sqrt 3$.  You need to choose the right one for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are two angles in the fundamental domain $(0,\pi)$ of the cotangent so that $2x=\frac\pi6+k\pi$. These are $\frac\pi{12}$ and $\frac\pi{12}+\frac\pi2=\frac{7\pi}{12}$. Your quadratic equation has roots at the cotangent of both of these angles.

Answer (score 0):

It comes from the fact that you solved a quadratic with nonzero discriminant, in this case being $$(-2\sqrt 3)^2-4(1)(-1)=12+4=16.$$